# How to run PhoneGap on a different WebView on Android?

Tags: android, html, cordova, webview

PhoneGap/Cordova is running on the native webview on Android browsers which is the webkit version 534.30 up to Android 4.4. I searched for alternatives to use a newer webview, e.g., Chromium based. Here is what I found:

1. https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps
2. [CrossWalk](https://crosswalk-project.org)
3. [cocoonjs](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/)

There are some drawbacks. When you add a compiled Chromium webview to your PhoneGap app you get up to 40MB in app size which is very much.

**Is there another way to use a different webview on Android than the native webview without increasing the app size to much?**

Comment: No, there is no other way yet. You have to add the whole browser, so the app size increases

Answer (score 1):

Think a webview is almost a complete browser. Currently the only option available for creators is to compile a free browser and add webview interface.

You can take a look to all the features supported by a chromium-based webview in the following link:
http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/202308176-Webview-Supported-APIs